Different output in VisualStudio and Codeblocks
I need a linear interpolation in 2D array. The output in Codeblocks is correct, but in VisualStudio is not.
I got 2 main functions.

Linear interpolation in 1D array:
Function is Y(X) and the result is Y(x).

Linear interpolation in 2D array:
Function is Y(X1, X2) and the result is Y(x, y).


And function to test it.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

double lin_int(int size, double* X, const double* Y, double x){
    int i;
    if (x >= *(X + size-1)){
        return *(Y + size-1);
    } else
    if (x <= *(X)){
        return *(Y);
    }
    for(i = 1; i < size; i++){
        if (*(X + i) >= x && *(X + i - 1) <= x){
            if (*(X+i) == *(X+i-1)){
                return *(Y + i - 1)+(*(Y + i)-*(Y + i - 1))*(x-*(X+i-1))/(*(X+i-1)*2); //два совпадающих значения в узлах (деление на ноль)
            }
            return *(Y + i - 1)+(*(Y + i)-*(Y + i - 1))*(x-*(X+i-1))/(*(X+i)-*(X+i-1));
        }
    }
}

/*
             |       X2[j]           y              X2[j+1]
_____________|_____________________________________________________________
X1[i]        |      Y[i][j]          x1            Y[i][j+1]
             |
x            |                     return
             |
X1[i+1]      |     Y[i+1][j]         x2           Y[i+1][j+1]
             |
X1[m]
X2[n]
Y[m][n]
*/
double lin_int_for_mass(int m, int n, double* X1, double* X2, const double* Y, double x, double y){
    int i;
    int j;
    double x1, x2;
    bool in_X1, in_X2;                                  //Проверки, что искомая точка за границей:
    if (x < *(X1) && y < *(X2)) return *Y;              //по X1 и X2 меньше оба значения x, y - возвращаем Y[0][0]
    if (x > *(X1+m) && y > *(X2+n)) return *(Y+m*n-1);  //по X1 и X2 больше оба значения x, y - возвращаем Y[m][n]
    if (x < *(X1)) x = *(X1);                           //по X1 значение x меньше X1[0] - ставим x = X1[0]
    if (y < *(X2)) y = *(X2);                           //по X2 значение y меньше X2[0] - ставим y = X2[0]
    if (x > *(X1+m-1)) x = *(X1+m-1);                   //по X1 значение x больше X1[m] - ставим x = X1[m]
    if (y > *(X2+n-1)) y = *(X2+n-1);                   //по X2 значение y больше X2[n] - ставим y = X2[n]
    for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++){
        if (x == *(X1 + i)){ //Проверка что мы в узле X1
            in_X1 = true;
            break;
        } else
        if (x > *(X1 + i) && x < *(X1 + i + 1)) break; //Если не в узле, фиксируем индекс предыдущего узла
    }
    for (j = 0; j < m-1; j++){
        if (y == *(X2 + j)){ //Проверка что мы в узле X2
            in_X2 = true;
            break;
        } else
        if (y > *(X2 + j) && y < *(X2 + j + 1)) break; //Если не в узле, фиксируем индекс предыдущего узла
    }

    if (in_X1 && in_X2) { //Если попали в два узла сетки, возвращаем уже известное значение
        return *((Y + i*n) + j);
    } else
    if (in_X1) { //Если в узле только по X1, возвращаем lin_int между узлами X2
        return lin_int(n, X2, (Y+i*n), y);
    } else
    if (in_X2) { //Если в узле только по X2, возвращаем lin_int между узлами X1
        x1 = *((Y+i*n)+j);
        x2 = *((Y+(i+1)*n)+j);
        if (*(X1+i+1) == *(X1+i)){
            return x1 + (x2-x1) * (x-*(X1+i)) / (*(X1+i)*2); //два совпадающих значения в узлах
        }
        return x1 + (x2-x1) * (x-*(X1+i)) / (*(X1+i+1) - *(X1+i));
    } else { //Если ни в какой узел не попали
        if (*(X1+i+1) == *(X1+i)){
            return x1 + (x2-x1) * (x-*(X1+i)) / (*(X1+i)*2); //два совпадающих значения в узлах
        }
        x1 = lin_int(n, X2, (Y+i*n), y); //Если не попали ни в какой узел, вычисляем x1, x2 и возвращаем lin_int между ними
        x2 = lin_int(n, X2, (Y+(i+1)*n), y);
        return x1 + (x2-x1) * (x-*(X1+i)) / (*(X1+i+1) - *(X1+i));
    }
}


void test_lin_int_mass(void){
    double X1[4] = { 0.3, 1.0, 4.0, 10.0 };
    double X2[3] = { 0.0, 90.0, 180.0 };
    double Y[4][3] =
        {/*                  0             90             180        */
        /*0.3*/            {1.0,         -0.107,         -0.5},
        /*1.0*/            {1.3,          -0.3,          -0.7},
        /*4.0*/            {1.5,          -0.2,          -0.6},
        /*10.*/            {1.53,        -0.253,         -0.5}
        };

    double i,j;
    for (i=0; i<=200; i+=15){
        printf("\t%.3lf", i);

    }
    printf("\n");
    for (i=0; i<=12; i+=1){
        printf("%.3lf", i);
        for(j=0; j<=200; j+=15){
            printf("\t%.3lf", lin_int_for_mass(4, 3, X1, X2, &Y[0][0], i, j));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main()
{
    test_lin_int_mass();
    return 0;
}

What is the reason of different outputs?
Wrong output (in VisualStudio):
    0.000   15.000  30.000  45.000  60.000  75.000  90.000  105.000 120.000 135.000 150.000 165.000 180.000 195.000
0.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500
1.000   1.300   1.300   1.300   1.300   1.300   1.300   -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500
2.000   1.300   -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500
3.000   1.300   -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500
4.000   1.500   -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500
5.000   1.500   -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500
6.000   1.500   -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500
7.000   1.500   -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500
8.000   1.500   -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500
9.000   1.500   -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500
10.000  1.500   -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500
11.000  1.500   -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500
12.000  1.500   -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500  -0.500

Right output(in Codeblocks):
    0.000   15.000  30.000  45.000  60.000  75.000  90.000  105.000 120.000 135.000 150.000 165.000 180.000 195.000
0.000   1.000   0.816   0.631   0.447   0.262   0.077   -0.107  -0.172  -0.238  -0.304  -0.369  -0.434  -0.500  -0.500
1.000   1.300   1.033   0.767   0.500   0.233   -0.033  -0.300  -0.367  -0.433  -0.500  -0.567  -0.633  -0.700  -0.700
2.000   1.367   1.094   0.822   0.550   0.278   0.006   -0.267  -0.333  -0.400  -0.467  -0.533  -0.600  -0.667  -0.667
3.000   1.433   1.156   0.878   0.600   0.322   0.044   -0.233  -0.300  -0.367  -0.433  -0.500  -0.567  -0.633  -0.633
4.000   1.500   1.217   0.933   0.650   0.367   0.083   -0.200  -0.267  -0.333  -0.400  -0.467  -0.533  -0.600  -0.600
5.000   1.505   1.219   0.934   0.648   0.362   0.077   -0.209  -0.271  -0.334  -0.396  -0.458  -0.521  -0.583  -0.583
6.000   1.510   1.222   0.934   0.646   0.358   0.070   -0.218  -0.276  -0.334  -0.392  -0.450  -0.508  -0.567  -0.567
7.000   1.515   1.225   0.935   0.644   0.354   0.064   -0.227  -0.280  -0.334  -0.388  -0.442  -0.496  -0.550  -0.550
8.000   1.520   1.227   0.935   0.642   0.350   0.057   -0.235  -0.285  -0.335  -0.384  -0.434  -0.484  -0.533  -0.533
9.000   1.525   1.230   0.935   0.640   0.346   0.051   -0.244  -0.290  -0.335  -0.380  -0.426  -0.471  -0.517  -0.517
10.000  1.530   1.233   0.936   0.639   0.341   0.044   -0.253  -0.294  -0.335  -0.377  -0.418  -0.459  -0.500  -0.500
11.000  1.530   1.233   0.936   0.639   0.341   0.044   -0.253  -0.294  -0.335  -0.377  -0.418  -0.459  -0.500  -0.500
12.000  1.530   1.233   0.936   0.639   0.341   0.044   -0.253  -0.294  -0.335  -0.377  -0.418  -0.459  -0.500  -0.500


Any time I read "Different behaviour here than there..." I think Undefined Behaviour. Do you know about that? In any case, please provide a [mre], ideally with hardcoded input, which demonstrates what you observe, preferrably accompanied by a statement that you really use it identically in both environments. Nice to have: English comments.

There are too many one letter variables in your code, it is hard to understand what they represent.

@Harith I wrote which variable is responsible for what, I hope you can understand it. I also added comments to represent the structure of arrays.

what is the correct output and what is the wrong output ? and how are they different ?

Added a godbolt for the sample https://godbolt.org/z/7af9W4Mnr

@JohannGerell just added a sanatizer and got a bug, https://godbolt.org/z/M38hsE4rM

Please enable compiler warnings: 'lin_int': not all control paths return a value. If there really are no other paths, then don't confuse the code by using unnecessary else statements.

Be wary of comparing floating point values for equality.

Added right and wrong outputs.

The function lin_int_for_mass() has Undefined Behavior in at least two places:

You do not initialize the variables x1 and x2 in every path through that function; in particular, if neither in_X1 or in_X2 are true, you may hit the return statement in line 77 without ever initializing them.
Same goes for the variables in_X1 and in_X2 themselves; you have UB unless both x == *(X1 + i) for any x, X1 and i, and y == *(X2 + j) for any y, X2 and j.

This problem might occur in other places of your code as well; as a general rule of thumb, avoid declaring a variable without initializing it. Unless you're using an ancient language standard, you don't need to declare your variables on top of your function and then assign them later (which you might forget to do); you can declare and initialize them right at the place where you need them.

The main problem was in function lin_int_for_mass. I didn't initialized in_X1 and in_X2 as false for default.
